# Not able to fix background color of div element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-events

I want my div element color to be fixed once a user clicks on it. But now, it keeps changing the color even after users click on it.

This is my code snippet which I have tried.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
        },  
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
        }, 
        click: function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
        }  
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Some Comment Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is happening explain more!

Comment: when i am click on div element background color is red but afterward the color will be change.
You can Run code snippet as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you Questions and comments, it seems that you want to keep the color to be red after that Div is clicked. But, after it clicked again, the div will bind to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event again.

If that is what you want, you need to do the checking when you click on div, whether you need to `bind` the event or `unbind` it.

Note : If you are using `JQuery` with a version greater than v1.7, its better to use `on` `off` rather than `bind` `unbind`

```
function  entering() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
}
function  leaving() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isBind = true;
    $('div').on('mouseenter',entering);
    $('div').on('mouseleave',leaving);
    $('div').on('click',function(){
            if (isBind)
            {
                $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
                $("div").off('mouseenter',entering);
                $("div").off('mouseleave',leaving);
                isBind = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $('div').on('mouseenter',entering);
                $('div').on('mouseleave',leaving);
                isBind = true;
            }
    });
});
```

working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jkq2wfjz/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").on({
            mouseenter: function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
            },  
            mouseleave: function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
            }, 
            click: function(){
                $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
                $("div").off();
                // As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated
            }  
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>Some Comment Text</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here `$("div").off();` is used to unbind all event listener so that no event will fire again.

Comment: It is work only for first time click. when i am click another time, color will be same as per your answer.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz - As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery script to following and it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var current_color = $(this).css("background-color");
        if(current_color != 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
            $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
        }
    },  
    mouseleave: function(){
        var current_color = $(this).css("background-color");
        if(current_color != 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'){
            $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
        }
    }, 
    click: function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
    }  
});
});
```

let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes but it works for only first time clicking. afterward, the color if not changeable on cliking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain `div` background color after click .. Obviously your code is not correct. You need to maintain or store the state of the `div` like a bool flag or some other technique.

As below you can achieve your task using `data-attribute` in `HTML`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            if( $(this).attr('data-isclicked')=="false")
            {
              $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
            }
        },  
        mouseleave: function(){
            if( $(this).attr('data-isclicked')=="false")
            {
              $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
            }
            
        }, 
        click: function(){
            $(this).attr('data-isclicked','true');
            $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
        }  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-isclicked='false'>1 Some Comment Text</div>
<div data-isclicked='false'>2 Some Comment Text</div>
<div data-isclicked='false'>3 Some Comment Text</div>
<div data-isclicked='false'>4 Some Comment Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
click: function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "Red");
    });
}
```